# Azure Web App System.UnauthorizedAccessException once deployed to Azure can't access shared folder on local network

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, file-upload, access-denied

We have a hybrid Azure/Local network.  I am able to access the shared drive \192.168.74.10\Shared\LIS\For Upload\Reports (on the local network) from a VM on the Azure network.  If I paste the address in file explorer it asks for a username and password.  Once given, I can access the report folder from the VM.

When I run the web app from Visual Studio from a computer that is VPNed into the network I am able to access the shared drive on 192.168.74.10.  The computer isn't part of the AD, just VPNed into the network.  Once the web app is deployed to the azure cloud I get System.UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to access the folder.

I copied the WrappedImpersonationContext code from another post.  Adding WrappedImpersonationContext allows my web app to access the folder from the computer VPNed into the network.

WrappedImpersonationContext code:

```
 public sealed class WrappedImpersonationContext
{
    public enum LogonType : int
    {
        Interactive = 2,
        Network = 3,
        Batch = 4,
        Service = 5,
        Unlock = 7,
        NetworkClearText = 8,
        NewCredentials = 9
    }

    public enum LogonProvider : int
    {
        Default = 0,  // LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT
        WinNT35 = 1,
        WinNT40 = 2,  // Use the NTLM logon provider.
        WinNT50 = 3   // Use the negotiate logon provider.
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "LogonUserW", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain,
        String lpszPassword, LogonType dwLogonType, LogonProvider dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    private string _domain, _password, _username;
    private IntPtr _token;
    private WindowsImpersonationContext _context;

    private bool IsInContext
    {
        get { return _context != null; }
    }

    public WrappedImpersonationContext(string domain, string username, string password)
    {
        _domain = String.IsNullOrEmpty(domain) ? "." : domain;
        _username = username;
        _password = password;
    }

    // Changes the Windows identity of this thread. Make sure to always call Leave() at the end.
    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public void Enter()
    {
        if (IsInContext)
            return;

        _token = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool logonSuccessfull = LogonUser(_username, _domain, _password, LogonType.NewCredentials, LogonProvider.WinNT50, ref _token);
        if (!logonSuccessfull)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(_token);
        _context = identity.Impersonate();

        Debug.WriteLine(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
    }

    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public void Leave()
    {
        if (!IsInContext)
            return;

        _context.Undo();

        if (_token != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            CloseHandle(_token);
        }
        _context = null;
    }
}
```

Code for uploading the files:

```
public ActionResult UploadDirectoryEncrypted()
    {

        int fileType = 2;

        StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountName"],
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountKey"]);

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps: true);

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        var impersonationContext = new WrappedImpersonationContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerDomain"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerUser"],  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerPassword"]);
        impersonationContext.Enter();

        string sourceDirectory = @"\\192.168.74.10\Shared\LIS\For Upload\Reports\";            

        var folder = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory);
        var files = folder.GetFiles();
        foreach (var fileInfo in files)
        {
            string blobName = fileInfo.Name;
            string blobFilePath = sourceDirectory + blobName;
            double accession_number = Convert.ToDouble(blobName.Substring(0, blobName.Length - 3));

            CloudBlobContainer container = GetContainer(blobClient, Convert.ToInt32(fileType));

            KeyVaultKeyResolver cloudResolver = new KeyVaultKeyResolver(GetToken);

            var rsa = cloudResolver.ResolveKeyAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyId"], CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            BlobEncryptionPolicy policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(rsa, null);
            BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions() { EncryptionPolicy = policy };

            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

            using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(blobFilePath))
                blob.UploadFromStream(stream, stream.Length, null, options, null);

            System.IO.File.Delete(blobFilePath);
        }
        impersonationContext.Leave();            
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
    }
```

I gave full control to Network Service, IUSR and IIS_IUSRS but am still getting the following access denied error.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Access to the path '\\192.168.74.10\Shared\LIS\For Upload\Reports' is 
denied.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 
'\\192.168.74.10\Shared\LIS\For Upload\Reports' is denied. 

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider 
granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. 
ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or 
Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool 
identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. 
If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the 
identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the 
authenticated request user. 

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, 
choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the 
appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the 
boxes for the desired access.
```

What can I do to gain access to the folder on the local network?

Answer (score 0):

Its recommended storing files in Azure storage not under any virtual path or directory as this may affect/restart site on the local network (VS).

Comment: is there microsoft documentation about this?